# How to return fake pods using the fake for kubeclient?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a unittest for some code which uses the Kubernetes go-client. My unittest uses the Kubernetes [fake](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/kubernetes/fake) to mock out Kubernetes. My unittest tries to create some fake pods to be returned by calls to Pods.List.

What's the proper way to create fake pods?

I first tried calling Pods.Create on the fake e.g

```
_, err := j.ClientSet.CoreV1().Pods(NAMESPACE).Create(
    &v1.Pod{
        TypeMeta: meta_v1.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "Pod",
            APIVersion: "v1",
        },
        ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: j.masterName(),
            Labels: map[string]string{
                "tag":   "",
            },
        },
    })

l, err := j.ClientSet.CoreV1().Pods(NAMESPACE).List(v1.ListOptions{})

if len(l.Items) == 0 {
    t.Fatalf("No pods were returned by list.")
}
```

However, the call to list pods didn't return the pod.

I then tried creating the pod when creating the fake; e.g.

```
j.ClientSet = fake.NewSimpleClientset(&v1.Pod{
    TypeMeta: meta_v1.TypeMeta{
        Kind: "pod",
    },
    ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta{
        Name: j.masterName(),
        Labels: map[string]string{
            "tag":   "",
        },
    },
})
```

With this code NewSimpleClientSet failed with a panic

```
panic: no matches for kind /, Kind=Pod [recovered]
        panic: no matches for kind /, Kind=Pod
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you fully implement the interface of `ClientSet`? It seems that something about resource kind you have not handled.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out in my case I was using a very old version of the Kubernetes client and fake. When I updated to the latest code it worked.